# Why is Ticks not honored by DateListPlot and DateListLogPlot?

Tags: plotting

In Mma 10.2, I see ticks on the following plot:

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 100}, 100]^2;
dates = {{1950, 1}, Automatic, "Month"};
DateListLogPlot[data, dates, Ticks -> None]
```

Most importantly, if I try to set custom ticks, they do not appear.  Is this a bug or for some reason intended?

Comment: It will be closed as simple mistake but don't worry. Probably every other plot has Axes not Frame by default and they have different option (Ticks, FrameTicks) to handle ticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ticks` is to `Axes` as `FrameTicks` is to `Frame`.

`DateListPlot` uses `Frame` by default instead of `Axes`, so you'll want to use `FrameTicks`.